# Is a Nested Loop inevitable in ST_Intersects in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I'm using PostGIS 9.6 and I have two tables, `usgovt` and `risk`. Both have spatial indexes and the database has just had a `VACUUM ANALYSE`.

`usgovt` has 142,598 rows, with a mean vertex count of 402 (and a max of 1393536):

```
category  | integer                     |
geom      | geometry(MultiPolygon,5070) |
```

`risk` has just 1 row with a vertex count of 94223:

```
 geom   | geometry(MultiPolygon,5070) |
```

I am querying the intersection of the two, but it is slow (380 seconds):

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
  SELECT g.category AS category
  FROM usgovt g, risk r
  WHERE
    ST_Intersects(g.geom, r.geom);
```

[Here is the explain](https://explain.depesz.com/s/1pTJ).

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=4.39..64.15 rows=48 width=2) (actual time=164.231..380784.381 rows=48456 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on risk r  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on usgovt g  (cost=4.39..63.09 rows=5 width=34) (actual time=164.223..380718.542 rows=48456 loops=1)
         Recheck Cond: (geom && r.geom)
         Filter: _st_intersects(geom, r.geom)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 71027
         Heap Blocks: exact=23099
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on usgovt_geom_idx  (cost=0.00..4.39 rows=14 width=0) (actual time=24.500..24.500 rows=119483 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (geom && r.geom)
 Planning time: 0.328 ms
 Execution time: 380855.965 ms
```

It looks like the slow part is the Nested Loop. Is this inevitable, or is there any way I can avoid it?

(If this seems like an odd query - I want to calculate the area of the intersection, but right now that query doesn't complete. So I'm starting by debuggging whether there's any way to speed up the intersection.)

Comment: This is just one example of why it's important to specify the exact row count and topology class of all tables, and to use a JOIN to force the query to use the most efficient plan. Please edit the question to clarify whether the "1GB" size refers to just the geometry, or the combined geometry and attributes. In addition to row count, mean vertex.count would provide insight into the root complexity.

Comment: @Vince thanks - I've updated the question with row and vertex counts, and the details of the `geom` columns.

Comment: The problem is that as risk only has one row, you are checking for the intersection of that row's geometry against every row's geometry in usgovt, which is going to be an expensive operation, given that risk has 94223 vertices. This might be why the analyser has chosen a bitmap index rather than a spatial index scan, even though the bounding box is being checked, as you see in the index cond: (geom && r.geom) part. This is also why you have a nested loop, because it means for every row in usgovt. You can try ` set enable_bitmapscan to off`; to force planning not to use a bitmap scan.

Comment: However, I suspect the slowness is simply down to the number of times you actaully have to check each of the lines betweeen those 94223 vertices for intersection.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any sensible approach to speeding this up, or is it just the way it is? Would it help to `ST_Union(g.geom)` first perhaps, then it would only be 1 intersection calculation rather than 142k?

Comment: If you want to know the area of each usgovt intersection with risk as an end result, then unioning won't help you, it might even slow it down.

Answer (score 1):

Any polygon with 1,393,536 vertices will slow down the entire query due to the CPU overhead caused by a complex geometry. Indexing won't fix this.

The fix is to create a copy of your table with much more efficient geometries generated using `ST_Subdivide(geom, 512)`; where 512 is the max vertices in each subdivided polygon (you may find 256 or 1024 is faster).

Then spatial indexing will significantly speed up the query.

*This requires PostGIS v2.2.0 or higher*